# Wwise and CUBE event for landing a jump

Tags: gameaudio, wwise

Hi Guys,

I have been recently playing around with Wwise and the CUBE game that you can download from AK's site. I've become somewhat comfortable with the program but am constantly hitting small walls (not literally). My problems stem from the game, and the lack of desirable switches and events that are not programmed into it. I've come across a few sites that gives some help on adding little features, but the one I've been searching for is an event for when you land from a jump (a normal jump). As far as I know, there is no event for this in CUBE.

Has anyone here with programming experience (which I have none of) written in this event within CUBE? I have no experience with writing code but am able to copy/paste and compile :)
Would anyone be open to sharing the code for that event (if not, that's completely fine)?

BTW, I came across Graham Gatheral's page, which has some nice examples which are all well explained if any one is interested :

http://www.gatheral.co.uk/index.html

Thanks

Comment: I'd be really interested in hearing about this too, I wanted to do my own edit of Cube with wWise but ran into the same problem you did, I'm no coder.

Answer (score 1):

a sound like that will often be hooked up thru an animation system.  That is a system, usually separate from the audio tool and sometimes outside the game tool, that allows the designer to attach 'cues' ('events' in wwise) to specific frames of an animation.  It is possible that for this example system they did not provide an animation sound system.